# Hbase master not running

Tags: hadoop, hbase

I am trying to run Hbase in a pseudo-distributed mode. I followed [this link](http://archanaschangale.wordpress.com/2013/08/31/installing-pseudo-distributed-hbase-on-ubuntu/).

I am using ubuntu version 12.04 Hbase version 0.94.8 Hadoop Version 2.4.0

In hbase/conf/hbase-env.sh, i added the following

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0_25

export HBASE_REGIONSERVERS=/usr/lib/hbase/hbase-0.94.8/conf/regionservers

export HBASE_MANAGES_ZK=true
```

Then I set the HBASE_HOME path in bashrc file

In hbase/conf/hbase-site.xml I added the following,

```
<configuration>

<property>

<name>hbase.rootdir</name>

<value>hdfs://localhost:9000/hbase</value>

</property>



<property>

<name>hbase.cluster.distributed</name>

<value>true</value>

</property>


<property>

<name>hbase.zookeeper.quorum</name>

<value>localhost</value>

</property>


<property>

<name>dfs.replication</name>

<value>1</value>

</property>


<property>

<name>hbase.zookeeper.property.clientPort</name>

<value>2181</value>

</property>


<property>

<name>hbase.zookeeper.property.dataDir</name>

<value>/home/prashasti/Installed/hbase-0.94.8/HBASE/zookeeper</value>

</property>

</configuration>
```

To prevent version mismatch between hadoop and hbase, I added

```
hadoop-common-2.4.0.jar
```

and

```
hadoop-mapreduce-client-core-2.4.0.jar
```

in hbase/lib folder

When I start hbase using

```
$./bin/start-hbase.sh
```

No error turns up, but the Hmaster doesn't start.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

can you pl try removing all the configuration parameters from hbase-site.xml except **hbase.rootdir** and then try starting the hbase.
Also comment out **export HBASE_REGIONSERVERS export HBASE_MANAGES_ZK** in hbase-env.xml

Comment: Finally the Hmaster did run.. but I am facing other issues. 
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.getInputStream(Ljava/net/Socket;)Lorg/apache/hadoop/net/SocketInputWrapper;

Comment: when you get this issue?

Comment: I get this issue when I try to check the master status on web UI and also when i try to create a table using Hbase shell.

Comment: can you pl copy hadoop core jar from hadoop root to hbase lib folder and then try.

Comment: There is no hadoop-core-2.4.0 jar in my hadoop home, where would it be located?

Comment: why does removing those configurations helps? I had the same issue and it helped