# hbase not running in pseudo distributed mode

Tags: hadoop, hbase

I am using Hbase version 0.94.8 and hadoop version 2.4.0 . While running Hbase in pseudo distributed mode, I get the following error on checking the master status,

Problem accessing /master-status. Reason:

```
org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.getInputStream(Ljava/net/Socket;)Lorg/apache/hadoop/net/SocketInputWrapper;
```

Caused by:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.getInputStream(Ljava/net/Socket;)Lorg/apache/hadoop/net/SocketInputWrapper;
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.HBaseClient$Connection.setupIOstreams(HBaseClient.java:437)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.HBaseClient.getConnection(HBaseClient.java:1124)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.HBaseClient.call(HBaseClient.java:974)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.WritableRpcEngine$Invoker.invoke(WritableRpcEngine.java:86)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy10.getProtocolVersion(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.WritableRpcEngine.getProxy(WritableRpcEngine.java:138)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation.getMaster(HConnectionManager.java:712)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HBaseAdmin.<init>(HBaseAdmin.java:126)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.MasterStatusServlet.doGet(MasterStatusServlet.java:56)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:707)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:820)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:511)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1221)
    at org.apache.hadoop.http.HttpServer$QuotingInputFilter.doFilter(HttpServer.java:835)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1212)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:399)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:766)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:450)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:230)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:326)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:542)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(HttpConnection.java:928)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:549)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:212)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:404)
    at org.mortbay.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:410)
    at org.mortbay.thread.QueuedThreadPool$PoolThread.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:582)
```

Comment: [Please do not ask the same question multiple times.](http://stackoverflow.com/q/24653368/580412)

Comment: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError always points to a missing lib. So Hbase is missing a library somwhere.

Answer (score 2):

Hbase - *0.94.8* and Hadoop - *2.4.0*  **are listed as NOT-Tested** by hbase.org. Reason for error can be *** Version compatability issue***. because Hbase depends on Hadoop jars.

The Hbase official documentation site has provided the [hadoop-hbase version compatability matrix](http://hbase.apache.org/book.html#basic.prerequisites) . please refer and choose Supported versions of Hadoop & Hbase.

Answer (score 0):

This issue comes when you don't have proper version of jar of Hadoop. You can login to your environment and get the hadoop version. You should have same version of jar file or you can check the jar files from $HADOOP_HOME/lib path.

It will give you the required jar file and you could be able to resolve this issue.